# Delete folder if sum of its TXT files is greater than 50 MB?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a server running and creating 10KB log TXT files every hour. When the TXT files reaches 50MB, I would like to purge all and keep only 10MB (so delete 40MB of files, the remaining 10MB would be only the most recent files).

I tought of using `dir`, like:

```
dir *.txt
```

In the before last line of `dir` there is something like this:

```
9 Rép(s)  566 773 248 octets
```

Then I would extract the last number of this line, and if this number is greater than 50 000 000 then I will delete all the first 40MB of files.

I have no idea how to proceed, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in batch without hurting yourself. Badly.

Using VBScript with a [disconnected recordset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.09.heyscriptingguy.aspx) might be a better approach.

```
Const adBigInt  = 20
Const adDate    = 7
Const adVarChar = 200

Const SizeThreshold = 52428800 'Byte
Const SizeLimit     = 10485760 'Byte

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set rs = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
rs.Fields.Append "path", adVarChar, 255
rs.Fields.Append "date", adDate
rs.Fields.Append "size", adBigInt
rs.Open

totalSize = 0

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Temp").Files
  rs.AddNew
  rs("path") = f.Path
  rs("date") = f.DateLastModified
  rs("size") = f.Size
  rs.Update
  totalSize = totalSize + f.Size
Next

If totalSize > SizeThreshold Then
  rs.Sort = "date ASC, size ASC"
  rs.MoveFirst

  Do Until rs.EOF Or totalSize < SizeLimit
    rs.MoveFirst
    fso.DeleteFile rs("path")
    totalSize = totalSize - CLng(rs("size"))
    rs.Delete
  Loop
End If

rs.Close
```